# popping my stack in c++

Tags: c++, stack

So my final program for class is due tomorrow, I've gotten this far with my code, it loads the stack correctly and I think it the isEmpty function works correctly, but my function isn't popping the stack. Just says "Popping 15" and doesn't continue. Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
/*
   Purpose of a program is to write a stack.cpp that will create a dynamic stack of int data type. 
 */


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct StackNode
{
   int value;
   StackNode * next;
};

bool isEmpty(StackNode * top);
void displayStack(StackNode * top);
void push(StackNode *& top, int num);
void pop(StackNode *& top, int &item);

int main()
{
   StackNode * top = NULL;
   bool status;
   int item;


   // Push the values 5, 10, and 15
   // onto the stack.
   cout << "Pushing 5 \n";
   push(top, 5);
   cout << "Pushing 10 \n";
   push(top, 10);
   cout << "Pushing 15 \n";
   push(top, 15);

   cout << endl;
   cout << "Display the numbers in the stack (from top to bottom): ";
   displayStack(top);
   cout << endl;

   cout << "Popping... \n";
   pop(top, item);
   cout << item << endl;
   pop(top, item);
   cout << item << endl;
   pop(top, item);
   cout << item << endl;

   // The stack is empty, but try to 
   // pop another value.
   cout << "\nAttempting to pop again... ";
   pop(top, item);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

bool isEmpty(StackNode * top) // Checks to see if the whole stack is empty
{
   if (!top)
   {
      return false;
   }
}

void displayStack(StackNode * top) // Displays the stack
{
   if(top)
   {
      displayStack(top->next);
      cout << top->value << " ";
   }
}

void push(StackNode *& top, int num) // Pushes a number onto the stack
{
   if (!top)
   {
      top = new StackNode;
      top->value = num;
      top->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      push(top->next, num);
   }
}

void pop(StackNode *& top, int &item) // clears the top number of the stack 
{
   if (top)
   {
      if (top->value)
      {
         item = top->value;
         pop(top->next, item);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why does pop call pop?

Comment: @Mat he's using it to traverse to the end of the list. 

Pop isn't actually modifying the stack. You don't need to traverse to the end of the stack each time you want to push or pop an item.

Comment: to continue popping the stack, i was doing it recursively but I think that's making my pop stack harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Why not use OOP and templates?

Comment: I'm not allowed to change anything in the main, and I have to use those four functions only.

Comment: There is am error is `isEmpty`. Not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in `push`. Your logic makes sure that it pushes the input at the bottom of the stack.

What you need is:

```
void push(StackNode *& top, int num)
{
   StackNode* temp = new StackNode;
   temp->value = num;
   temp->next = top;
   top = temp;
}
```

`pop` can also be simplified to:

```
void pop(StackNode *& top, int &item)
{
   if (top)
   {
      item = top->value;
      StackNode* temp = top;
      top = top->next;
      delete temp; // If you don't delete temp, it is a memory leak.
   }
}
```

`isEmpty` can be simplified to:

```
bool isEmpty(StackNode * top)
{
   return (top == NULL);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare temp

Comment: Might as well as add a fix for `isEmpty` for completeness